# Google Adwords in android

Tags: android, google-ads-api

HI..I need to do Google Adwords in android.see link:

[https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?_*u=1355887856&*_c=6610511936&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1355887856&__c=6610511936&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none)

I need to create like this.I donno how to get api for this..How to do this.?

Comment: Don't got what you want to say? And mark the text as link if you want to make it a link.

Comment: My link..https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?_u=1355887856&_c=6610511936&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Google ads SDK](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/) in your apllication.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply..But i just wanna know how to get api to do this.?i dont know anything about adword..im sry to say this..

Comment: do you know `Google AdSense` and `Google AdWords` are different jargons?

Answer (score 1):

I use the AdWords API regularly and you need to use the TargetingIdeaService at http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService.html

However, I'm not familiar with Android so don't know where you should start with it. Usually it's best to use one of their client libraries at http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/clientlibraries.html but I don't think there is one for Android. There is a Java based one so maybe that'll work. There's a tutorial about using the service on the AdWords API blog at http://adwordsapi.blogspot.com/2009/11/discover-v2009-getting-ideas-with.html